# How to get a collection of Laravel Spark developers?

Tags: laravel, laravel-spark

I'm using Laravel Spark and I'm reading the docs, but I can't find any method to get a list of my Spark developers. It looks like the only usage I can find that references the protected $developers variable is the middleware which compares an email address with Spark::developer().

Is there anything like Spark::getDevelopers() that would either return the protected array, or a collection of the actual users with matching emails?

I could do this but it seems needlessly expensive:

```
$users = User::get();
$developers = $users->filter(function ($user) {
    return Spark::developer($user->email);
});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This does the trick without having to modify anything:

```
$developers = User::whereIn('email', Spark::$developers)->get();
```

Answer (score -1):

Add this to ManagesAppDetails.php

```
public static function getDevelopers(){       
   return self::$developers;
}
```

then you can do:

```
spark::getDevelopers()
```

hope this helps!

Comment: That would work but that's a framework file and would be overwritten on update.